# How do I fit the borders in the input text type?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is what i am getting]
I want the border to align with the box , what is wrong with my code ? Any help would be appreciated .

```css
 .contact {
      background-color: rgb(233, 230, 227);
      height: 200px;
    }
    .contact h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .form {
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 344px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      transform: translatex(450px);
    }
    .form input {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 7px;
      /* font-size: 20px;*/
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
  <section class="contact">
            <h3>
                Contact Us
            </h3>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the default or defined padding and border in the 100% width:

```css
.contact {
  background-color: rgb(233, 230, 227);
  height: 200px;
}

.contact h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 344px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  /* font-size: 20px;*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <h3>
    Contact Us
  </h3>
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
  </div>
</section>
```

P.S.: You obviously tried to center the form field horizontally. This probably might work the way you did it with the particular parent container width you are using, but I changed it to a more universally working method (see the three parameters added/changed in the `.form` CSS rule)

Answer (score 2):

You would need a `box-sizing: border-box`. I recommend you to set this for all your HTML elements. It would save you a lot of time, like so:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box; /* that is all you are missing*/
}
.contact {
  background-color: rgb(233, 230, 227);
  height: 200px;
}
.contact h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 344px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  transform: translatex(450px);
}
.form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  /* font-size: 20px;*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
        <h3>
            Contact Us
        </h3>
        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-box`  set border on only input that will be fit.

```css
 .contact {
      background-color: rgb(233, 230, 227);
      height: 200px;
    }
    .contact h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .form {
      max-width: 344px;
      padding: 7px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    .form input[type=text] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid red;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
  <section class="contact">
            <h3>
                Contact Us
            </h3>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </section>
```